# Using local Clang-format when developing in a remote Docker container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I'm using VS Code connected to a Docker container: project files and compilation tools are located there. Host system is macOS Big Sur.

I'm using the [Clang-Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format) extension, but the `clang-format` available in the Docker image is very outdated and cannot be upgraded (for external reasons), so I cannot use the project's `.clang-format` file (which contains newer directives).

I have the newest version of `clang-format` installed locally in the host computer. Is there any way to configure VS Code to use that version of `clang-format` instead of the one in the Docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local copy cannot be used because VS Code will run it inside the Docker instead of in the host, and the binaries are not compatible.

The best way I've found to do this is to download `clang-format` for Linux in the host, share it with the container and tell VS Code to use it:

1. Download (or compile) `clang-format` compatible with the Linux version of the container. In my case the container is based on Ubuntu 20.04, so there is already a precompiled version of clang+LLVM available [in the official project repo](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-13.0.0).
2. Uncompress it into a directory that can be bound to the container (you can do it in Docker Desktop, under Settings > Resources > File sharing). In my case I have one prepared for this: `~/shared`, so I uncompressed it under `~/shared/clang+llvm-13.0.0`.
3. In the `docker-compose.yml` file mount the local directory where `clang-format` is located (use the remote directory that best works for you):

```yaml
services:
    volumes:
      - ~/shared/clang+llvm-13.0.0:/home/user/clang+llvm-13.0.0:ro
```

4. Finally, set the path to the executable in the user's `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "clang-format.executable": "/home/user/clang+llvm-13.0.0/bin/clang-format"
}
```

The only drawback of this approach is that the `clang-format.executable` setting is user-wide, there is no workspace-level setting, so the change apply universally. In my case it is not a big issue because everything is done in containers, but I know it may not be the best option for mixed setups.